# How to get group of records with latest date using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with the following fields:

```
ID | MarketID | CommodityID | CurrencyID | PriceValue | Year | Month
```

With the following data:

```
1  | 100 | 30 | 15 | 3.465 | 2018 | 03
2  | 100 | 30 | 15 | 2.372 | 2018 | 04
3  | 100 | 32 | 15 | 1.431 | 2018 | 02
4  | 100 | 32 | 15 | 1.855 | 2018 | 03
5  | 100 | 32 | 15 | 2.065 | 2018 | 04
6  | 101 | 30 | 15 | 7.732 | 2018 | 03
7  | 101 | 30 | 15 | 8.978 | 2018 | 04
8  | 101 | 32 | 15 | 4.601 | 2018 | 02
9  | 101 | 32 | 18 | 0.138 | 2017 | 12
10 | 101 | 32 | 18 | 0.165 | 2018 | 03
11 | 101 | 32 | 18 | 0.202 | 2018 | 04
```

As you can see the date is (unfortunately) saved as an integer in the Year and Month fields.

**I want to get from the above data, using LINQ to Entities (EF6), the latest PriceValue for each Market-Commodity-Currency record.**

So the **expected result** should be:

```
2  | 100 | 30 | 15 | 2.372 | 2018 | 04
5  | 100 | 32 | 15 | 2.065 | 2018 | 04
7  | 101 | 30 | 15 | 8.978 | 2018 | 04
8  | 101 | 32 | 15 | 4.601 | 2018 | 02
11 | 101 | 32 | 18 | 0.202 | 2018 | 04
```

I've **tried** with the following queries but none of them can give me the expected results:

```
var lastValues = (from a in Analysis
                     group a by a.ID into g
                     select g.OrderByDescending(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month)));
```

and the following that has more sense of the previous one, but I loose the PriceValue field:

```
var lastValues = (from a in Analysis
                  group a by new {a.MarketID, a.CommodityID, a.CurrencyID } into g
                  select new
                  {
                     g.Key.MarketID,
                     g.Key.CommodityID,
                     g.Key.CurrencyID,
                     date = g.Max(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month))
                  });
```

Is there a way to have a **single LINQ query** to get only the records with the latest date as I've described above?

Comment: I had a similar issue with a Year, Periode(kinda weird semester). To not reproduce the calculation and as it was not convertible to a datetime. those information were map to a new object that implement a IComparer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the way to include also the PriceValue in the results.

Starting from the last query I've posted, I've to simply add the

```
g.OrderByDescending(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month)).FirstOrDefault().PriceValue
```

So it will be:

```
var lastValues = (from a in Analysis
                  group a by new {a.MarketID, a.CommodityID, a.CurrencyID } into g
                  select new
                  {
                     g.Key.MarketID,
                     g.Key.CommodityID,
                     g.Key.CurrencyID,
                     date = g.Max(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month)),
                     g.OrderByDescending(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month)).FirstOrDefault().PriceValue
                  });
```

I prefer this solution as it's based on the current query I've developed.

Comment: Real Kludge instead of just using new DateTime(year, month,day)

Comment: @jdweng Isn't it better in performance use integer than converting to datetime?

Comment: Well you could of multiplied by 12 instead of 100 and it would work, but your mind is only thinking in decimal.  My mind thinks efficiently and I would shift left by 4 binary places and then add to eliminate the multiplication.  My teachers always taught that software needs to be maintained and using tricks make it harder for other people to understand the code.  I never said your method was bad, just a kludge.

Comment: `date = g.Max(t => ((t.Year* 100) + t.Month)),` seems misleading as a name when it's not a "date"

Comment: Mark : It is a date, just not standard format. The definition of Date in Wiki : A calendar date is a reference to a particular day represented within a calendar system.  So Giox is using a different calendar system that create unique numbers for each day that are incremental as time goes along.  Just skips some integers.  If he multiplied by 12 then no numbers would be skipped.

Comment: @jdweng - yeah I see it is a "date" of sorts (I should have added more clarity to the comment).  I would have (probably) used a Truncated Julian date. Lillian day number or some such with a specific definition.
As compared to a DateTime date.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MARKETID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CommodityID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CurrencyID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PriceValue", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(int));
            //ID | MarketID | CommodityID | CurrencyID | PriceValue | Year | Month
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1  , 100 , 30 , 15 , 3.465 , 2018 , 03});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2  , 100 , 30 , 15 , 2.372 , 2018 , 04});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3  , 100 , 32 , 15 , 1.431 , 2018 , 02});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4  , 100 , 32 , 15 , 1.855 , 2018 , 03});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5  , 100 , 32 , 15 , 2.065 , 2018 , 04});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {6  , 101 , 30 , 15 , 7.732 , 2018 , 03});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {7  , 101 , 30 , 15 , 8.978 , 2018 , 04});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {8  , 101 , 32 , 15 , 4.601 , 2018 , 02});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {9  , 101 , 32 , 18 , 0.138 , 2017 , 12});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {10 , 101 , 32 , 18 , 0.165 , 2018 , 03});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 101, 32, 18, 0.202, 2018, 04 });

            List<DataRow> results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderByDescending(x => new DateTime(x.Field<int>("Year"), x.Field<int>("Month"), 1))
                .GroupBy(x => new { market = x.Field<int>("MarketID"), commodity = x.Field<int>("CommodityID"), currency = x.Field<int>("CurrencyID") })
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This  Linq Query

```
     var lastValues = (from ak in Analysis
                          group ak by new { ak.MarketID, ak.CommodityID, ak.CurrencyID } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              g.Key.MarketID,
                              g.Key.CommodityID,
                              g.Key.CurrencyID,
                              pricevalue = g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Year).ThenByDescending(c=>c.Month).FirstOrDefault().PriceValue,
                              year = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Year).ThenByDescending(c => c.Month).FirstOrDefault().Year,
                              month = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Year).ThenByDescending(c => c.Month).FirstOrDefault().Month
                          });
```

Using Orderby and ThenBy